# What is the probability of a random natural number being a power of $10$

Tags: probability, divisibility

I know as $n \to \infty$, this probability is $0$, I know this because there are approximately $\log_{10}(n)$ powers of $10$ less than $n$ and so the probability of a natural number in the interval $[1, n]$ being a power of $10$ is approx $\frac{\log_1(n)}{n}$ which goes to zero as $n \to \infty$. Thus the answer is $0$.

I was wondering if there was a simpler way of doing this? Rather than using logs? Maybe sum to infinity of a geometric progression? Could anyone help!? Thank you!

Comment: Until you assign a probability distribution to the natural numbers this doesn't make sense.

Comment: There are $n$ powers of 10 in the first $10^n$ natural numbers. You can also say that as $n \to \infty$, you have approximately $$\dfrac{n}{10^n}$$ chance of picking one? This is not much different than using logs, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may answer this question by considering a "uniform" distribution over natural numbers that is a **charge** (*finitely additive probability measure*) on $(\mathbb{N},2^{\mathbb{N}})$. Specifically, for $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ let $(\delta_A)_n=\mathbf{1}_A(n)$ and let $\mathsf{P}(A):=T(\delta_A)$, where $T$ is a [Banach limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit) on $\ell^{\infty}$.

For example, $\mathsf{P}(\mathbb{N})=1$, $\mathsf{P}(A)=0$ for any finite set $A$, and $\mathsf{P}(\{n\in \mathbb{N}:n\equiv1 \mod 2\})=1/2$.

Now, using your argument, $\mathsf{P}(\{n\in\mathbb{N}:n\text{ is a power of $10$}\})=0$.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer, but the word *finitely* should be bold, italicised and underlined, and a letter different from $\mathsf{P}$ should be used as well to not give the impression that this is a probability measure in the most common sense.

Comment: Other than that, +1.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I agree. On one hand, it is a formalization of the intuition behind "picking a random natural number". On the other hand, some usual properties related to σ-additive measures do not hold.

Answer (score 3):

To answer a question such as "what is the probability that ...", you need a precise probabilistic framework to be defined first. When no framework is defined, it's implicitly understood that the uniform distribution is considered.

When it comes to natural numbers, the problem is there is no uniform discrete probability measure there. So the question is ill-defined: what *is* a random natural number?

Your attempt is the best I can imagine to try and make sense of the question being asked, but it still is a different question.

---

Edit: @d.k.o.'s answer also comes close to addressing your problem, but you should be very careful that it's not a probability measure in the usual sense, since it's finitely additive instead of countably additive. You should keep that in mind at all times if you wish to remember and cite that example.

Comment: Question: the OP is calculating the asymptotic density of powers of ten within the natural numbers. Is this not the asymptotic distribution of the sequence of uniform distributions on $[1,n]$? Wouldn't that make the OP's calculation a calculation of probability after all?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Any attempt at doing something uniform will inevitably hit the same problem as d.k.o.'s answer. Yes, you can define $$p(X)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\#(X\cap [1,n])}{n}$$ but then $p(\{k\})=0$ for any fixed $k$, while $p(\Bbb N)=1$, so you're missing the countable additivity axiom.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

What you are computing is **not** a probability. You can define a uniform probability law on $[1,n]$, compute probability of the event $A:$ $'k\in [1,n] \textit{ is a power of 10 }'$ as a function of $n$, P_A(n), and take limit
$$P_A=\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{lim}P_A(n)=0$$
This is OK, but the limit $P_A$ is **not** a probability.