# probability of a number divisible by $7$

Tags: probability

> If $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (set of natural numbers ). Then finding the probability that $\displaystyle \binom{n}{7}$ is divisible by $7,$ is

what i try

$$\binom{n}{7}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)(n-6)}{7!}$$

Let $n=7k+i, i=1,2,3,4,5,6$ amd $k\in \mathbb{W}$

How do i solve it Help me please

Comment: Small point : this is not a probability, but rather refers to the limit of the proportion of numbers below $N$ satisfying this property, as $N \to \infty$. Note that the uniform probability can't be defined on an infinite set.

Comment: This question will make sense as soon as you define what probability measure you are using. Be aware that there is no uniform measure, [as was already discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3465681/what-is-the-probability-of-a-random-natural-number-being-a-power-of-10/3465691?noredirect=1#comment7125401_3465691).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг It can be defined on some infinite sets. Just not _countably_ infinite sets.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, good point.

Comment: @DonThousand's answer (now deleted) was essentially correct. If $n=7k+i$ with $0\le i<7$, then exactly one of $n,n-1,\dots,n-6$ is divisible by 7. It is divisible by $7^2$ iff $k$ is divisible by 7. The only reasonable interpretation of probability is the limit (as $N\to\infty$) of the proportion of numbers less than $N$ which give divisibility by 7. So the answer is 1/7 as he said. Also it tends to 1/7 quite quickly. For example, it is a reasonable approximation for 4 digit numbers and an excellent one for 6 digit numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you have exactly one $7$ in the prime factorisation of the denominator of your fraction. You also have exactly one multiple of 7 in the product in the numerator. Thus, the result is divisible by $7$ exactly when that multiple of $7$ is also a multiple of $7^2$. That is: whenever $n$ is $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,$ or $6$ modulo $49$. That is $7$ of the $49$ values modulo $49$, so your probability is precisely $$\frac{7}{49} = \frac{1}{7}.$$

Comment: Please read the comments under the question. This question is not well defined since there is no uniform probability distribution of the naturals.

Comment: @DonThousand I think you are being too picky. Surely 1/7 is the only reasonable answer. See my comment under the question.

Comment: @almagest Just saw it. I agree with your interpretation, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @DonThousand "Probability" in such situations universally means "natural density".