# Basic Probability.

Tags: probability

What is the probability that l get a certain whole number, say 2 out of the set of the natural numbers. Is it zero ?

Further more, what is the probability of obtaining an even number,  Is it 1/2 ?

Is it meaningful to define probability over an infinite set or not ?

Comment: You can only speak of such probabilities if a probability measure has been given on $\mathbb N$. There is no uniform distribution on $\mathbb N$.

Comment: This has been discussed recently in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3465681/what-is-the-probability-of-a-random-natural-number-being-a-power-of-10/3465691#3465691)

Comment: @drhab.  So no probability measure exists on the set of natural numbers. Is it true for all other infinite sets too ?

Comment: I am not saying that no probability measure exists on $\mathbb N$ but that no *uniform* probability measure (i.e. one such that all numbers have equal probability to be chosen) exists. On every non-empty set (also infinite) we can define probability measures. The non-existence of a uniform probability measure implicitly says that we cannot use terminology like "a randomly drawn number from $\mathbb N$". This terminology is senseless for infinite sets.

Comment: Makes sense now.

Comment: Makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining probability over an infinite set is tricky. You cannot do it so that all singletons have equal probability, else it would be zero.

Thus you need to define a density of probability in order to state which is the probability of having a certain result. In $\mathbb N$ there is no probability measure that is uniform.

But you could give meaning to choosing at random by fixing a probability of choosing each number.

E.g.: $P(n)=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ is a possibility: you have one possibility in two of choosing $0$, one in four of choosing $1$ and so on. For this choice, $P(even)=2 P(odd)$ hence $P(even)=\frac{2}{3}$.

Obviously you can give a different distribution of probability and get a different result. The point is: since $\mathbb N$ is infinite, it will not be uniform.

Comment: Interesting, it seems to be quite flexible and allows different measures.

Comment: Indeed it is. Actually on any space you can fix a probability measure such that some basic rules apply (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure)  and then various theorems of probability apply. The choice of probability measure is a pre-mathematic problem, i.e. you have to chose what it does mean randomly choose in your situation. Uniform probability for a finite set of singletons is just a simple case of the theory.