# Reference request: theorem concerning random addition mod a positive integer

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory, reference-request

I am wondering if anyone can provide reference to a work providing roughly the following statement.

Let $N>2$ be a positive even integer, and $x_0$ be a nonnegative integer less than $N$.  Further, consider a partition of the $N$ elements less than $N$ into two *equally sized* "classes", $A$ and $B$, so that for every $y \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $y \mod N$ falls into either the $A$ or $B$ class (i.e. is an element of the set $A$ or $B$).

I am looking for a theorem that says, roughly, for uniformly randomly chosen $y \in \mathbb{N}$, the probability that $x_0 + y \mod N$ is in either class $A$ or $B$ is equal.  This is a somewhat trivial statement, but I would like a reference nonetheless.

Comment: What is the measure for $y \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: You need to give a proper definition of "randomly chosen integer".

Comment: @Joppy I suppose you can just take each $y$ to have measure zero (and be uniformly randomly chosen), but I would also welcome a related question where the $y$ were uniformly randomly chosen from a finite interval and each $y$ is then taken to have positive measure.

Comment: @d.k.o. Thanks, I edited the question: I need the $y$ to be *uniformly randomly chosen*.  Alternatively, I would also welcome an answer where the $y$ were uniformly randomly chosen from a large albeit finite interval of $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a **charge** on $(\mathbb{N},2^{\mathbb{N}})$ of the form $\mathsf{P}(C):=T(\delta_C)$, where $T$ is a Banach limit on $\ell^{\infty}$ and $(\delta_C)_n=\mathbf{1}_C(n)$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3465681/what-is-the-probability-of-a-random-natural-number-being-a-power-of-10)).

Let $H_C:=\{y\in \mathbb{N}:(x_0+y \mod N)\in C\}$. Then
$$
\mathsf{P}(H_A)=\frac{1}{2} \quad\text{and}\quad \mathsf{P}(H_B)=1-\mathsf{P}(H_A)=\frac{1}{2}
$$
because the Césaro limit of the sequence $\delta_{H_A}$ is $1/2$.